# Convert string array from curl to separate new lines in a file

Tags: json, bash, curl, jq

Calling `curl localhost:8080/api` returns something like `["test1, "test2", "test3"]`

I wanted to convert it to:

```
test1
test2
test3
```

and then add it to a file

I am trying things like:

```
curl localhost:8080/api | printf "%s\n" >>> file.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [jq](/questions/tagged/jq) to parse & manipulate JSON data from command line.

```
$ echo '["test1", "test2", "test3"]' | jq -r '.[]'
test1
test2
test3
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `curl` *and* `jq` you could give [xidel](/questions/tagged/xidel) a try. It's a JSON parser (unlike `sed`!) and it can open all sorts of online sources. You could try:

```
xidel -s "localhost:8080/api" -e '$json()' > file.txt
```

or

```
xidel -s "localhost:8080/api" -e 'file:write-text-lines("file.txt",$json())'
```

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason you cannot install [jq](/questions/tagged/jq), you can try something like:

```
$ echo '["test1, "test2", "test3"]' |  sed 's/[]\[",]/\n/g' | grep -v '^\ *$'
test1
test2
test3
```

i.e.:

```
$ curl localhost:8080/api | sed 's/[]\[",]/\n/g' | grep -v '^\ *$' >>> file.txt
```